# Double integral with expotential function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate
$\int_A e^{3+y^2}dxdy$
where A is triangle with apices in $(0,0), (1,-1), (0,-1)$.
I cannot seem to be able to do this one, any suggestions? Answer listed is: $\frac{e^3}{2}(e-1)$

Comment: Integration by parts - gotten me nowhere

Comment: Try draw a graph and integrate $x$ first, then $y$.

Comment: By the way, how do you use integration by parts when doing double integral?

Comment: Another little hint: get rid of the constant $e^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lokk at the picture:

[image]

Indeed, $x\in [0..1]$ and as I showed, the range for $y$ is $[-x,-1]$. But this doesnot work. $\exp(y^2)$ can not be integrated and so described as elementary functions. So let change the ranges as $y\in[-1,0]$ and $x\in[0..-y]$. Now we have: $$\int_{-1}^0\exp(3+y^2)dy\int_0^{-y}dx$$

Comment: Thanks, just before you posted reply I realized I put wrong boundaries in the second option(was -1 instead of 0). Now it works nicely.

Comment: You r Welcome. Thanks